# Настройка конфигурации Spring Boot + Vue + Nginx + HTTPS

Tags: vue.js, nginx, spring-boot, vue-router

У меня есть Spring Boot приложение, с Vue на фронтенде. Собрал jar и опубликовал его на свой сервер с ОС Ubuntu 18.
Т.к. Vue работает с history mod и если обновить страницу, то можно получить 404.

Настроил это дело так:

```
server{
listen 80;
server_name localhost;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @proxy;
}

location @proxy {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_intercept_errors on;
    recursive_error_pages on;
}

location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
}
}
```

Работает. 404 обрабатывает корректно и отдает index.html

Создал бесплатный сертификат. Добавил новые настройки

```
server {
listen 443 ssl;
server_name localhost;


ssl on;
ssl_certificate /var/www/httpd-cert/online-ege/--.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /var/www/httpd-cert/online-ege/--.key;
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers ECDH:+AES256:-3DES:RSA+AES:!NULL:!RC4;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @proxy;
}

location @proxy {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_intercept_errors on;
    recursive_error_pages on;
}
}
```

И тут опять при перезагрузке странички выдает 404. Пытался по-разному изменить конфиг, но ничего не выходит. Сам https работает корректно и страницы отдает правильно

Comment: 404-ю отдает nginx или сервер, который стоит дальше?

Comment: Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Thu Dec 05 12:51:39 MSK 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
Судя по всему сервер

Comment: Нужно сделать так, чтобы на любой запрос сервер отвечал одной и той же страницей. Той, где у Вас приложение подключается

Comment: @Дмытрык, я вроде так и сделал. По http все работает как надо, хотя была такая же проблема, но ее я решил.На https код практически такой же, только порт прописали и ключи.

Comment: @Дмытрык, наверное, так будет понятнее. https://simplege.ru/ вот тут мы нажимает на ссылку и переходит на роут /login, после переходя обновляем страницу и получаем 404

Answer (score 0):

Как и написал @Дмытрык, дело было не в nginx, как я думал изначально. Ошибку выдает сервер, а значит дело в нем.

Добавил контроллер:

```
package com.project.backend.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class OtherController {
@RequestMapping("{?:(?:(?!api|static|\\.).)*}/**")
  public String redirectApi() {     
    return "/index.html";
} 
}
```

Все стало работать, в том числе и по https.